# Current timestamp in ISO 8601 UTC time (ie: 2013-11-03T00:45:54+02:00)

Tags: date, google-apps-script, date-formatting, iso8601

Can someone please help me how to format timestamp in ISO 8601 UTC time?

I want the date to be formatted like this `2020-10-03T00:45:54+02:00`

I have tried this in App Script.

```
 Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ");
```

It is getting this output 2020-10-03T08:50:18+0000
I want the timezone to be formatted like this TwoDigitHours : Minutes

Answer (score 4):

- Use [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)  for UTC ISO8601 string:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

- [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) accepts 3 arguments:

  - `Date` object
  - Timezone
  - `SimpleDateFormat` string
- For, [ISO8601 timestring use `X` instead of `Z`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- For a  specific timezone, use that timezone(`GMT+2`) as second argument instead of UTC

  ```
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+2" , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
  ```
- Alternatively, Use [`Session.getScriptTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone) or [`Spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone) instead for the second argument:

  ```
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

  //Or

  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
  ```